# Can't get tutorial to work: Build a Physics-Based Platformer in Under an Hour

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d

So I found this tutorial online and the idea of learning this in under an hour appealed to me:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/build-a-physics-based-platformer-in-under-an-hour/

Problem is I can't get it to work upon reaching Step 14 - when I test movie as the second paragraph says I get errors. **Edit** The problem had been narrowed down to Line 31 world = null. Perhaps what more specifically I want to know is *What is world suppose to be?* How do I define world so that I get the end result demonstrated in the tutorial?

**Edit 2** Okay so I'm sort of making progress here, for anyone who cares to know. I replaced the *listenWhileVisible* method used in the tutorial with the *addEventListener* method so I don't even need to mention the world property. So now no errors BUT at this point in the tutorial I'm suppose to be able to move the hero left and right, which isn't happening. Any help why? new code updated below

---

I tried test movie after each step and it didn't have any errors until I applied the *view.characters.HeroCharacter* class to the my hero movie clip. So it seems the problem is in the HeroCharacter.as. So I went rogue from the instructions and fiddled with HeroCharacter.as. The FlashDevelop didn't autogenerate all the necessary imports when I copy pasted the code from the tutorial. I narrowed the problem down to finally getting this error in the output window in Flash:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at misc::Entity/listenWhileVisible()
at view.characters::HeroCharacter/create()
at misc::Entity/ensureCreated()
at Function/<anonymous>()
```

Here is the Actionscript

```
package view.characters 
{
import Box2DAS.Collision.b2WorldManifold;
import Box2DAS.Common.V2;
import Box2DAS.Dynamics.b2World;
import Box2DAS.Dynamics.ContactEvent;
import Box2DAS.Dynamics.StepEvent;
import misc.Input;
import misc.Util;   
import shapes.Box;
import wck.BodyShape;
import wck.ContactList;
import wck.World;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Hexel Colorado
 */
public class HeroCharacter extends Box {

    private var contacts:ContactList;

    public override function create():void {
        reportBeginContact = true;
        reportEndContact = true;
        contacts = new ContactList();
        contacts.listenTo(this);

        fixedRotation = true;

        addEventListener(StepEvent.STEP, world_stepEventHandler, false, 0, true);
        addEventListener(ContactEvent.BEGIN_CONTACT, this_beginContactHandler, false, 0, true);

        super.create();
    }

    private function world_stepEventHandler(e:StepEvent):void
    {
        var left:Boolean = Input.kd('LEFT', 'A');
        var right:Boolean = Input.kd('RIGHT', 'D');
        var jump:Boolean = Input.kp('UP', ' ', 'W');

        if (jump) {
            b2body.ApplyImpulse(new V2(0, -2), b2body.GetWorldCenter());
        }
        else if(left) {
            b2body.ApplyImpulse(new V2(-2, 0), b2body.GetWorldCenter());
        }
        else if(right) {
            b2body.ApplyImpulse(new V2(2, 0), b2body.GetWorldCenter());
        }
    }

    private function this_beginContactHandler(e:ContactEvent):void
    {
    }

}
}
```

I've stopped at Paragraph 2 of Step 14 and won't continue with the rest of the tutorial until I can get this figured out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Found the problem!! For the sake of googlers, here is what's wrong: you need to put super.create at the BEGINNING of the override function because if you don't create first then world wouldn't exist YET. Found out here: http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=6378

I really don't like this tutorial now. Claims can be done in less than hour - takes hours to figure out problem.

Comment: well, it took me 10-15 minutes if you notice the super.create() in my last comment in my answer :) but I understand what you meant. Not sure why he didn't fix that (probably an old version of box2d). Try to answer it now, not sure if 25 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think i got it wrong bellow actually, it seems it's in the super.create() function. Test this trace bellow anyway just in case and then figure out the debugger and get back with that specific line of code causing trouble.
Edit 2: nah, it's not in super.create(), error data confused me for a second, do this bellow.

Most probably the variable "world" is not defined.

input the first line (trace) into your code like this:

```
trace("world = "+world);
listenWhileVisible(world, StepEvent.STEP, world_stepEventHandler, false, 0, true);
listenWhileVisible(this, ContactEvent.BEGIN_CONTACT, this_beginContactHandler, false, 0, true);
```

It should show something like: 
world = null 
world = undefined;

Also, learn to debug an aplication with a debugger. I start a remote debugging session in cases when I'm not sure what's going on (I should be correct now).  The debugger will pinpoint the exact offending line to use.

Another way to debug, though slower is to input a bunch of trace statements and see which ones fail to fire. The code in between is causing the problem. I do not recommend this.

**Make sure** you learn to use a debugger, it will save you hundreds of hours in a span of a year or two (my case).

[remote debug in flash](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSE9184681-3417-4849-B487-8D6C2F8CC688.html)

the standalone player download is the same, the only thing different is:

Select Debug > Begin Remote Debug Session > ActionScript 3.0.

In flash develop this is:

Debug > Start Remote Session

For now check out that trace, and if you don't know how to fix it, post a second question or more code here. **Then learn to use the debugger**.

[Debugger tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joWldbcp1So)

The tutorial is in a different language (Java), but concentrate on the debugger concepts, not code (Step over, Step Into, Step out, yada yada). The tracking part of the debugger is not present in Flex so disregard after 2:50.

Get comfortable with Step Into, Step Out, Step Over. Extremely powerfull.

Also, on the left side (lower left), you can view the state of objects in memory (the data inside properties). It beats tracing variables to figure out values (like above).

Comment: Thanks for all the info, but I had already figured that the problem was that the world was undefined. I did do what you said anyways and the trace did say world = null.

What I really want to know, and I probably should have just made this clear in my original question, is what exactly is world, in the case of this tutorial, suppose to be defined as? What exactly am I suppose to define world as, or what object or whatever is suppose to be named world? I tried naming the *World* movie clip instance "world" but that didn't solve it.

So simply put what I'm looking for is a case specific answer

Comment: not sure why it's not defined, I don't know enough about Box2D Alchemy port. either: 1) it's supposed to be set automatically by box2D b) it's set manually somewhere in code though it seems it's 1) since "ensureCreated" is checked by Box2D class Entity before calling create (it could be that this overload of create() messes things up, try super.create() in front of all the code in the function... Otherwise use the debugger and dig around your code then alchemy... Few can answer it from this "distance".

Comment: Found the problem (I posted it in a comment to the original question since StackOverflow doesn't let me post an answer yet.